# Why Fourier transform to solve this PDE

Tags: fourier-transform, fluid-dynamics

I'm reading a paper and has the linearized NS equation and follows it by getting the solution through a Fourier transform. What is the thought behind this? Meaning, why use a Fourier transform?

$ \rho\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} = -\nabla \mathbf{p} + \eta \nabla^2 \mathbf{v}$

Comment: Because it’s a standard technique in PDE theory.

Comment: Because it transforms gradient into $x$

Comment: $\mathbf{p}$ is the pressure and should *not* be marked as a vector, should it?

Answer (score 0):

Applying the Fourier transform on the space coordinates $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$ turns the PDE into an ODE:
$$
\rho\frac{d\hat{\mathbf{v}}}{dt} = -i\mathbf{k} \hat{p} - \eta k^2 \hat{\mathbf{v}},
$$
where $\mathbf{k}=(k_1,k_2,k_3)$ is the new variable (often called *wave vector*), $k=|\mathbf{k}|,$ and $\hat{}$ denotes transformed quantity. I have here assumed that $\rho$ and $\eta$ are constants. The symbol $i$ is the imaginary unit.

ODE's are usually easier to solve than PDE's. For example, the above equation has solutions
$$
\hat{\mathbf{v}} = -i \mathbf{k} e^{-\frac{\eta}{\rho}k^2t} \int e^{\frac{\eta}{\rho}k^2t} \hat{p} \, dt + e^{-\frac{\eta}{\rho}k^2t} C(\mathbf{k}),
$$
where $\int \cdot \, dt$ denotes anti-derivative (primitive function) and $C$ is some rather arbitrary function.